# dead HP elitebook 640

Tags: 20.04, hp

Ubuntu 20.04.4 with all updates until this morning. Elitebook 640 with 32gb of ram. Kernel 5.13 I think. While updating this morning on AC power the laptop fell into sleep and then died, loss power I am unable to regain power on state. removed battery,removed cmos battery no luck. Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If the device cannot power on when plugged in or not plugged in, that's a hardware issue and not an Ubuntu one.  The device **does not power on** regardless of what you do, correct?  It doesn't start to boot and fail or something, it just doesn't power on at all?  And you have tried holding the power button for ~10 seconds to force off anything, and then turn it back on?  If that also doesn't work, then chances are the device is busted and that's not something *we* can fix.

Comment: correct no power on no boot,holding power button for 15 seconds provides no happiness, I guess its time to start shopping for a new machine. thanks Thomas for your knowledge.

Comment: I'm assuming it's out of warranty, otherwise HP might be able to help replace parts, etc.  Otherwise, yeah, you're going to need a new system.

Comment: this is hardware related and should belong to another stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment and your response, your system does not power on under any circumstances.

Based on that, I have to say that this sounds more like your hardware has simply died, and is not fixable by Ask Ubuntu as it's not a software issue.

If this is the case, the only three options you have are a computer repair store who probably won't be able to fix it, contact HP if it's under warranty and they can probably do some hardware repair, or get a new computer.

Unfortunately, hardware death like this is not an ubuntu issue.

Comment: I only was looking for answers here because everyone is so knowledgeable,and this happened during the update process. Just seemed odd that I had a problem during update, never had this happened before, but I guess a first time for everything or terrible luck!